# How to horizontally center a unity3D game in a div?

Tags: css, unity-game-engine

It seems that there is no way the center a [Unity 3d game](http://www.scarywebgames.com/typocalypse) using CSS. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try like this?

```
#unityPlayer{margin:0px auto;}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wasn't thinking to add a code for the player itself ever.